# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a form that stores a stock in my database, when I enter one stock it persists the information and when I try to add another stock I get an exception 'cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table'

In my model I have my `STOCKID` property declared and in my T-SQL it is set as `IDENTITY(1,1)`.

In my model I added `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` but that hasn't helped

Any suggestions?

Model

```
public class Stock
{
    #region Day 1's

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]       
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LowFloatStocks] 
(
    [Id]                   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Date]                 DATE            NOT NULL,
    [Ticker]               NVARCHAR (4)    NOT NULL,
    [PreviousClose]        DECIMAL (4, 2)  DEFAULT ((4.00)) NOT NULL,
    [PM_OpeningPrice]      DECIMAL (18, 2) DEFAULT ((3)) NOT NULL,
    [OpeningPrice]         DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PMFadePercent]        AS (ROUND(([OpeningPrice] - [PM_OpeningPrice]) / [PM_OpeningPrice], (4)) * (100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [GainPercent]          AS (ROUND(([High] - [OpeningPrice]) / [OpeningPrice], (4)) * (100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [GapPercent]           AS (ROUND(([OpeningPrice] - [PreviousClose]) / [PreviousClose], (4)) * (100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Spike]                DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [1stSpike%]            AS (ROUND(([Spike] - [OpeningPrice]) / [OpeningPrice], (4)) * (100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [High]                 DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [HighPercent]          AS (ROUND(([High] - [PreviousClose]) / [PreviousClose], (4)) * (100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Low]                  DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [LowPercent]           AS (ROUND(([Low] - [PreviousClose]) / [PreviousClose], (4)) * (100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Close]                DECIMAL (18, 2) DEFAULT ((4)) NOT NULL,
    [ClosePercent]         AS              (round(([Close]-[PreviousClose])/[PreviousClose],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [ClosevHigh]           AS              (round(([High]-[Close])/[Close], (4))*(100)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [ClosevOpen]           AS              (round(([OpeningPrice]-[Close])/[OpeningPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [CloseLessEqualToOpen] AS              (CONVERT([nchar](3),case when [Close]<=[OpeningPrice] then 'Yes' else 'No' end)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [CloseRed]             AS              (CONVERT([nchar](3),case when [Close]<[OpeningPrice] then 'Yes' else 'No' end)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Catalyst]             NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Float]                DECIMAL (18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [Dilution]             NCHAR (3)       NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Add Stock Method

```
public ICommand AddCommand => _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.AddStock()));


    #endregion 

    #region Actions

    private void AddStock()
    {
        using (var stocks = new AppDbContext())
        {
            stocks.LowFloatStocks.Add(stock);
            stocks.SaveChanges();
            Stocks = stocks.LowFloatStocks.ToList();
            Clear();


        }
    }
```

Comment: have you added migration and updated the database?

Comment: It's database first? Do I have to use Migrations

Comment: are you also using fluent API for configuration? Can you show the code which is inserting into DB

Comment: I edited the question to show my Addstock method, no I'm not using fuent API

Comment: what is the value of `stock.Id`

Comment: Ok so I have noticed that when I try add the second entry it is trying to store the Id as the first entry?

Comment: yes, so try to set it 0 explicitly before saving. just give a try

Comment: Yeah, try what @viveknuna suggested:

stock.Id = 0;
stocks.LowFloatStocks.Add(stock);
stocks.SaveChanges();

Comment: Ok thats working now,would there be a better solution for that or should I just leave it how it is? Thanks for the help guys

Comment: You could find out where your "Id" Property gets a value from by putting a Breakpoint in the Setter and removing the Code that assigns a Value to the "Id". If that's not possible, just stay with this Solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` if you want to create they Keys yourself. `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` means, that you let the Database handle the Creation of the Primary Key. This is generally the best Option, because two instances of your Software trying to create the same Primary Key will result in an Error. This is an unlikely Scenario, but still: Let the Database create the Primary Keys. As you are using Database First, you do not have the Option to change the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` without updating your Database. If you created a Code First Model from Database, you do have the Option to change the `DatabaseGeneratedOption`, create a new Migration and Update the Database. But that may be undesirable, because Entity Framework might drop the entire Table and re-create it.

Please show the Code that creates the Entity added in `stocks.LowFloatStocks.Add(stock);`. Did you assign a value to `Id`? If so, try not to do that.

Otherwise, try the Solution suggested by @viveknuna in the Comments:

```
stock.Id = 0; 
stocks.LowFloatStocks.Add(stock); 
stocks.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I do want the database to create the keys itself, what I don't understand is why it does it on the first entry and not the second? @Robert Bantele

Comment: Low float stocks is just a ` public DbSet<Stock> LowFloatStocks
        { get; set; }`

Comment: Yeah but what I am interested in is the Code that creates the "stock"
If your first Entry in your List has the Value 0 as Id (which is the default for "int") then it will work. But if the next Entry gets the Value 1 for some reason, the Insert will fail because you manually assigned a Value to a DatabaseGenerated Property

Comment: I have text boxes that are bound to my stock properties '`public string Ticker
        {
            get { return stock.Ticker; }
            set { stock.Ticker = value; OnPropertyChanged("Ticker"); }
        }


        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return Date = stock.Date; }
            set { stock.Date = value; }
        }